Not getting the Chat History between 2 Users (Using Strapi and Socket.io with React Native)
Hey community I am using the Strapi and Socket.io to implement one on one chatting means real time chatting with React Native.
My implementation is working fine Sending and receiving message is working fine .But the chat history is not getting fetched it is showing the Null array Although there are messages available in strapi content manager or in Database .
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  Keyboard,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Platform,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
} from 'react-native';
import {WebSocketService} from '../../../services/WebSocketService';
import {format} from 'date-fns';
import {backendBaseUrl} from '../../../services/WebSocketService';
import {useRoute} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import apiEndPoints from '../../../constants/apiEndPoints';
import {DefaultEventsMap} from '@socket.io/component-emitter';
import {Socket} from 'socket.io-client';
import {Image} from 'react-native';
import images from '../../../assets/images';
import useStyles from './style';
import icons from '../../../assets/icons';

interface Message {
  id: number;
  attributes: {
    content: string;
    sender: {
      data: {
        id: number;
      };
    };
    recipient: {
      data: {
        id: number;
      };
    };
    timestamp: string;
  };
}

interface RouteParams {
  data: number;
  name: string;
  friendData: any;
}

const Chatopen: React.FC = ({navigation}) => {
  const {styles, colors, sizes} = useStyles();

  const userToken = useSelector((state: any) => state.user?.user?.jwt);
  const userId = useSelector((state: any) => state.user?.user?.user?.id);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Message[]>([]);
  const [messageInput, setMessageInput] = useState<string>('');
  const route = useRoute();
  const {data, name, friendData} = route.params as RouteParams;
  let friendId = data;
  // console.log('Friend Id:', data);
  // console.log('UserId', userId);
  // console.log('Name is ', name);
  console.log('Friend Data is  ', JSON.stringify(friendData, null, 2));

  useEffect(() => {
    let socket: Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>;

    const connectWebSocket = async () => {
      if (userToken) {
        socket = WebSocketService(userToken);
        console.log('socket');
        socket.on('connect', () => {
          console.log('Connected to WebSocket');
        });

        socket.on('message:create', (message: {data: Message}) => {
          console.log('Received message:', message);
          setMessages(prevMessages => [...prevMessages, message.data]);
        });
      }
    };
    fetchMessages();
    connectWebSocket();

    return () => {
      if (socket) {
        socket.off('message:create');
        socket.disconnect();
      }
    };
  }, [userToken, friendId]);

  const fetchMessages = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `${backendBaseUrl}/api/messages?populate=*&filters[$or][0][sender][id][$eq]=${friendId}&filters[$or][0][recipient][id][$eq]=${userId}&filters[$or][1][sender][id][$eq]=${userId}&filters[$or][1][recipient][id][$eq]=${friendId}&pagination[page]=1&pagination[pageSize]=10`,

        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        },
      );
      const responseData = await response?.json();
      console.log('Hello Testing this functions');
      console.log('Response Data', responseData);

      if (responseData?.data) {
        setMessages(responseData?.data);
      } else {
        setMessages([]); // Ensure it's an empty array if there's no data
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching messages:', error);
    }
  };
  console.log(
    'Response ================= >> ',
    JSON.stringify(messages, null, 2),
  );

  const sendMessage = async () => {
    if (messageInput.trim() === '') return;

    const newMessage = {
      data: {
        content: messageInput,
        sender: userId,
        recipient: friendId,
        timestamp: formattedDate(),
      },
    };

    try {
      const token = userToken;
      await fetch(`${apiEndPoints.BASE_URL}/api/messages?populate=*`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(newMessage),
      });

      setMessageInput('');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending messages:', error);
    }
  };

  const formattedDate = () => {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    return format(currentDate, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <View style={styles.chatHeaderContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
            <Image source={images.ARROW_LEFT} tintColor={colors.BACKGROUND} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Image
            source={{
              uri: `${apiEndPoints.BASE_URL}${friendData.profileImage.url}`,
            }}
            style={styles.dpImageStyles}
          />
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>{name}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
        style={{
          flex: 1,
        }}>
        {messages && messages.length > 0 ? (
          messages.map(item => (
            <View
              key={item.id.toString()}
              style={[
                styles.message,
                item?.attributes?.recipient?.data?.[0]?.id === userId
                  ? styles.receivedMessage
                  : styles.sentMessage,
              ]}>
              <Text style={styles.messageText}>{item.attributes.content}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.timestamp}>{item.attributes.timeStamp}</Text>
            </View>
          ))
        ) : (
          <Text
            style={{
              textAlign: 'center',
              fontSize: 16,
              color: '#333',
              marginTop: 16,
            }}>
            No messages yet
          </Text>
        )}
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            value={messageInput}
            placeholderTextColor={'black'}
            onChangeText={text => {
              setMessageInput(text);
            }}
            placeholder="Type a message..."
          />
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.sendButton} onPress={sendMessage}>
            <Image source={icons.SEND} tintColor={'#008000'} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Chatopen;

This is my code and i have also tried the GPT's Solution where it asked me to add pagination but didn't got the results now any one please help me it approx 7 days fighting with this bug.
